# Error deploying to LocalStack with message "[ServiceName] has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable"

Tags: localstack

I'm trying to deploy a CloudFormation stack to LocalStack but I'm getting an error.  I *think* that it is related to the message "has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable".

These are the commands I am running.  The first two commands seem to run fine, but I get the error on the third.

```
cdklocal synth --no-staging --app "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts packages/localstack-pipeline/index.ts" > template.yaml
cdklocal bootstrap --app "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts packages/localstack-pipeline/index.ts"
cdklocal deploy --app "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts packages/localstack-pipeline/index.ts" --require-approval never
```

Below is the verbose log output.  (I also included the screenshot for the pretty colors.)

```
LenderReportingPipelineStack: deploying...
Retrieved account ID 000000000000 from disk cache
Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-000000000000-us-east-1'.
Waiting for stack CDKToolkit to finish creating or updating...
[0%] start: Publishing a5774a0664d245dfd1d6b06a7c700d2bbdcc4cb179851ac3124e6347fc826f58:000000000000-us-east-1
Retrieved account ID 000000000000 from disk cache
Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-000000000000-us-east-1'.
[0%] check: Check s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-000000000000-us-east-1/a5774a0664d245dfd1d6b06a7c700d2bbdcc4cb179851ac3124e6347fc826f58.json
[0%] found: Found s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-000000000000-us-east-1/a5774a0664d245dfd1d6b06a7c700d2bbdcc4cb179851ac3124e6347fc826f58.json
[100%] success: Published a5774a0664d245dfd1d6b06a7c700d2bbdcc4cb179851ac3124e6347fc826f58:000000000000-us-east-1
LenderReportingPipelineStack: checking if we can skip deploy
LenderReportingPipelineStack: template has changed
LenderReportingPipelineStack: deploying...
Removing existing change set with name cdk-deploy-change-set if it exists
Attempting to create ChangeSet with name cdk-deploy-change-set to update stack LenderReportingPipelineStack
LenderReportingPipelineStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
Initiated creation of changeset: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:000000000000:changeSet/cdk-deploy-change-set/e1f5df83; waiting for it to finish creating...
Waiting for changeset cdk-deploy-change-set on stack LenderReportingPipelineStack to finish creating...
Initiating execution of changeset arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:000000000000:changeSet/cdk-deploy-change-set/e1f5df83 on stack LenderReportingPipelineStack
Execution of changeset arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:000000000000:changeSet/cdk-deploy-change-set/e1f5df83 on stack LenderReportingPipelineStack has started; waiting for the update to complete...
Waiting for stack LenderReportingPipelineStack to finish creating or updating...
Stack LenderReportingPipelineStack has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (CREATE_IN_PROGRESS (Deployment succeeded))
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | LenderReportingPipelineStack
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucketEncryptionKey (PipelineArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyF5BF0670)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyAlias (PipelineArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyAlias94A07392)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucket (PipelineArtifactsBucketAEA9A052)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucket/Policy (PipelineArtifactsBucketPolicyF53CCC52)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Role (PipelineRoleB27FAA37)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Role/DefaultPolicy (PipelineRoleDefaultPolicy7BDC1ABB)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline (Pipeline9850B417)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Build/Synth/CodePipelineActionRole (PipelineBuildSynthCodePipelineActionRole4E7A6C97)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Build/Synth/CodePipelineActionRole/DefaultPolicy (PipelineBuildSynthCodePipelineActionRoleDefaultPolicy92C90290)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Build/Synth/CdkBuildProject/Role (PipelineBuildSynthCdkBuildProjectRole231EEA2A)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Build/Synth/CdkBuildProject/Role/DefaultPolicy (PipelineBuildSynthCdkBuildProjectRoleDefaultPolicyFB6C941C)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Build/Synth/CdkBuildProject (PipelineBuildSynthCdkBuildProject6BEFA8E6)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutate/CodePipelineActionRole (PipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutateCodePipelineActionRoleD6D4E5CF)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutate/CodePipelineActionRole/DefaultPolicy (PipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutateCodePipelineActionRoleDefaultPolicyE626265B)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:56 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/local/Migrations/CodePipelineActionRole (PipelinelocalMigrationsCodePipelineActionRole80230725)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/local/Migrations/CodePipelineActionRole/DefaultPolicy (PipelinelocalMigrationsCodePipelineActionRoleDefaultPolicyDA557DA9)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/local/Migrations/Project/Role (PipelinelocalMigrationsProjectRole137B1A17)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/local/Migrations/Project/Role/DefaultPolicy (PipelinelocalMigrationsProjectRoleDefaultPolicy527888FB)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/local/Migrations/Project (PipelinelocalMigrationsProject746BB2AD)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutation/Role (PipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutationRole57E559E8)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutation/Role/DefaultPolicy (PipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutationRoleDefaultPolicyA225DA4E)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutation (PipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutationDAA41400)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileRole (PipelineAssetsFileRole59943A77)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:57 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileRole/DefaultPolicy (PipelineAssetsFileRoleDefaultPolicy14DB8755)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset1/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset185A67CB4)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset2/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset24D2D639B)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset3/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset3FE71B523)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset4/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset474303B7D)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset5/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset5184A5C2F)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset6/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset669C72F3C)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset7/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset7A51C54D0)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:58 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset8/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset81DAB433B)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset9/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset9F08741A2)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset10/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset102484C317)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset11/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset11D534F05C)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset12/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset12E916E136)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset13/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset13BC3E73E7)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:51:59 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset14/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset14A3CA232F)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:52:00 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Assets/FileAsset15/Default (PipelineAssetsFileAsset15B22B8501)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  0/42 | 7:52:00 AM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | CDKMetadata/Default (CDKMetadata)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  1/42 | 7:52:05 AM | UPDATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucketEncryptionKey (PipelineArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyF5BF0670)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  2/42 | 7:52:05 AM | UPDATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyAlias (PipelineArtifactsBucketEncryptionKeyAlias94A07392)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  3/42 | 7:52:05 AM | UPDATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucket (PipelineArtifactsBucketAEA9A052)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  4/42 | 7:52:06 AM | UPDATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/ArtifactsBucket/Policy (PipelineArtifactsBucketPolicyF53CCC52)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  5/42 | 7:52:06 AM | UPDATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | Pipeline/Pipeline/Role (PipelineRoleB27FAA37)
LenderReportingPipelineStack |  5/42 | 7:52:07 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  | LenderReportingPipelineStack

Failed resources:

 ❌  LenderReportingPipelineStack failed: Error: The stack named LenderReportingPipelineStack failed to deploy: CREATE_FAILED (Deployment failed)
    at waitForStackDeploy (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/cloudformation.ts:309:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at prepareAndExecuteChangeSet (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:355:26)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:208:24)
    at initCommandLine (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:310:12)

The stack named LenderReportingPipelineStack failed to deploy: CREATE_FAILED (Deployment failed)
Error: The stack named LenderReportingPipelineStack failed to deploy: CREATE_FAILED (Deployment failed)
    at waitForStackDeploy (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/cloudformation.ts:309:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at prepareAndExecuteChangeSet (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:355:26)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:208:24)
    at initCommandLine (/home/jonathanbyrne/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:310:12)
```

[image]